# Tuple has no item when I am using the cross validation

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:,[2,3]]
y = iris.target

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm=SVC(kernel='linear',C=7.5)    
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
cv = ShuffleSplit(X_train.shape[0], n_iter=10, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
parameters={'kernel':('linear','rbf'),'C':[1, 10, 100, 1000],'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001]}
```

I am getting correct output till here.

```
classifier=GridSearchCV(svm,cv,parameters)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

The **error** after this comment is:
'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'

I am not sure why this is happening. Is it because the "**parameters**" should have just one parameter?

Comment: post the *full stack trace*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate the GridSearchCV instance here:

```
classifier=GridSearchCV(svm,cv,parameters)
```

You are including cv as the second positional argument. cv is a keyword argument and the second positional is param_grid (presumably what you intend to pass for parameters). I am basing this on the description of the API here: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Try constructing like so:

```
classifier=GridSearchCV(svm,parameters,cv=cv)
```

If this fails, it would really help to see the entire Traceback you get.